# Timestamp Data loaded into DATE column can't convert

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a simple problem:
I am currently trying to insert data as excel file into my database (APEX).
One of the tables I am loading is a timestamp column `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` but the column I am loading it in is Date format `mm/dd/yyyy`. When inserted, the column is displayed as Date `mm/dd/yyyy`, but when I try to Query the table looking for a date, no data is found.

here is my Query :
`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE_f = '01/20/2023'`

I suppose that even if the data is displayed as `Date` format as the column table is a `Date` column, it is still in `Timestamp` ...

If you have any idea on what the problem could be and how I could fix it ? (Convert my Column type maybe)
(I need the Data as Date format, and I cannot make the transformation in the Excel file)

Thank's for Helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle a `DATE` is a binary data-type composed of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is *NEVER** stored in any particular human readable format.

Therefore, if you load data with year-to-second components then your `DATE` will still have year-to-second components.

*(And if you load a date with only year-to-day components then your `DATE` will have those year-to-day components and will be given the default time components of midnight.)*

> When inserted, the column is displayed as Date `mm/dd/yyyy`

That is the **display** format that your client application happens to be using; it is not the same as the binary data that the database stores in the background.

Your client application (Apex) is trying to be helplful and is converting the binary value into something that you, the user, can understand and it is doing that by applying a default format model to the date. That model happens to be
`mm/dd/yyyy` which will not show the time components of the date; but those time components still exist even if they are not being displayed.

> here is my Query : `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE_f = '01/20/2023'`

Your query is effectively:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DATE_f = TO_DATE(
                  '01/20/2023',
                  ( SELECT value
                    FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                    WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
                );
```

Since your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter is `mm/dd/yyyy` then the conversion is successful and the date will be given the default time component of midnight. So this will only work if the date in your database has a time component of midnight; if it has any non-mindnight time component then it cannot match it

What you can do is match on a range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DATE_f >= DATE '2023-01-20'
AND    DATE_f <  DATE '2023-01-21'
```

or, you can match on the time component as well:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DATE_f = DATE '2023-01-20' + INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND
```

or, using a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DATE_f = TIMESTAMP '2023-01-20 12:34:56'
```

or, using `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DATE_f = TO_DATE('2023-01-20 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

You could also use `TRUNC`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  TRUNC(DATE_f) = DATE '2023-01-20';
```

But Oracle would not be able to use an index on the `DATE_F` column and would need a function-based index on `TRUNC(date_f)`. Using a range or matching an exact time does allow an index to be used.

---

If you want to change the format model that Oracle uses for implicit conversion from string-to-date and date-to-strings then you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

or, if you want to apply an explicit format to the dates then you can use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       TO_CHAR(DATE_f, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS date_f
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DATE_f >= DATE '2023-01-20'
AND    DATE_f <  DATE '2023-01-21'
```